# Applying the correct activity lifecycle methods

Tags: java, android

Updated

This is my listview app:

[image]

I click the email option which starts an intent and loads my email activity:

[image]

If the user clicks 'back' the listview is blank:

[image]

This is my method for setting the listview:

```
    public class view extends ListActivity {

ImageButton searchButton;
EditText searchName;
ListView searchedListResults;
long idToPass;
String numReturned;
String email;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
DBHandler getCons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    searchedListResults = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    list();

    searchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);

    searchedListResults.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            searchedListResults.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    });

    getCons = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            getCons.open();
            return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());

        }

    });
    searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

private void list() {
    DBHandler DBsearchRef = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    DBHandler search = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    search.open();
    Cursor cursor = search.getData();
    search.close();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBsearchRef.KEY_NAME,
            DBsearchRef.KEY_TEL, DBsearchRef.KEY_EMAIL,
            DBsearchRef.KEY_COMMENTS };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtNameSet, R.id.txtContactSet,
            R.id.txtEmailSet, R.id.txtCommentSet };

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.searchagain,
            cursor, from, to);
    searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    list();

    searchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);

    searchedListResults.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            searchedListResults.refreshDrawableState();

        }

    });

    getCons = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            getCons.open();
            return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());

        }

    });
    searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int list_posistion,
        long item_id) {
    idToPass = item_id;

    idToPass = item_id;

    DBHandler num = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    num.open();
    numReturned = num.getNum(idToPass);

    email = num.getEmail(idToPass);
    num.close();

    final CharSequence[] items = { "Call Contact", "Email Contact",
            "Edit Contact", "Add Appointment" };

    Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Contact Options:");

    alertDialogBuilder.setItems(items,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (items[item].equals("Call Contact")) {

                        Intent makeCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                                Uri.parse("tel:" + numReturned));
                        startActivity(makeCall);
                    }

                    else if (items[item].equals("Email Contact")) {

                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                                "com.example.flybaseapp.ContactsEmail");
                        emailIntent.putExtra("passedEmailAdd", email);
                        startActivity(emailIntent);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Edit Contact")) {

                        Intent Edit = new Intent(
                                "com.example.flybaseapp.viewEdit");
                        Edit.putExtra("passedID", idToPass);
                        startActivity(Edit);

                    }

                    else if (items[item].equals("Add Appointment")) {

                        Intent conAdd = new Intent(
                                "com.example.flybaseapp.AddAppointmentContact");
                        conAdd.putExtra("newpassedID", idToPass);
                        startActivity(conAdd);

                    }
                }

            });

    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}
```

Is it a case of setting this in an overriden onResume method?

Comment: I'm confused on what you want to know. The only `Activity` method you need to implement is `onCreate()`. You don't need to implement the others unless you need/want to do something special in them in which case we can't tell you that without more detail. If its working then I don't see any problem except you say you need to close your cursors

Comment: @codeMagic many thansk for your reply Within this code I have functions such as filters and editing the information within the listview that loads new intents (such as an edit page) as far as I was aware I needed to override methods such as onPause() when this occurs then onResume() when it is restarted?

Comment: No, the system will override those methods when necessary according to the [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) but you may override them if you need extra functionality say to do some extra when the `Activity` resumes then you may override `onResume()` and do what is needed there

Comment: @codeMagic are these methods done 'automatically' in the code of the activity? I wasnt aware of this is thats the case.

Comment: I have added an answer that may clarify it for you a little better. If not, please ask. And yes, they will be run automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) will run the necessary methods when it is time even if they aren't written in your code. `onCreate()` is the only one that is necessary to for you to `override`. All others will be run according to what `state` your `Activity` is in. You can, however, `override` any or all of these methods if necessary.

For example, since `onResume()` is run every time your `Activity` becomes visible but `onCreate()` is only run when the `Actviity` is first created, you may choose to put code in `onResume()` to ensure it is run every time the `Activity` becomes visible. Or maybe you want to save a variable when the `Activity` is being destroyed

```
@Override
public void finish()
{
    super.finish();
    // save variable to sharedprefs or wherever here
}
```

Comment: Now that makes sense. I could never work out why they needed to be overidden as it seemed like it should be something down automatically...so it looks like my understading was correct. Many thansk for your explantation. It looks like it is simply a case that im closing my cursors in the wrong manner which is giving my errors. I also receieve a cursor invalid statement in fillwindows()error. Again this seems like a cursor error?

Comment: I'm glad I could help clear it up for you. Yes, this sounds like a `cursor` issue. Create a post with the relevant DB code if you can't narrow that down

Comment: Just to add I have managed to sort these cursor issues out and installed my app. All works fine bar the fact that when i click back onto my listview page, my listview is blank. I have update my question to highlight this. Im under the assumption this is where i need tooverride onResums() to redisplay my list view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have since not seeing that much of the code but you may need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`. Have you verified that your adapter has values when you return? If you don't call `finish()` on your `Activity` with the list then it should be the same when you press the back button

Comment: I much appreciate your assiatance! I have kinda answered my own question by recalling my on list() method in onresume. It does reload my listview which is good...only issue now is i seem to loose focus on the edittext filter. To add, I am inclusing the filtering code in the onresume method.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it figured out! :)

Comment: The listview reset yeah it seems on the right track, but as mentioned now my filter dosent work when the onResume(0 is called. Ive once again loaded my whole class. Please excuse the messiness of onResume() as I have simply copied my filter from my onCreate()

Comment: I restarted my emulator and now the filter works! Strange eclipse quirk but many thanks codeMagic it all works now!

Comment: Ok, was just about to suggest something but I'm glad you got it going and you are welcome. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

The Android Activity Lifecycle can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The activity **[lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)** is already implementing all the stages for your Activity. Except the onCreate() which you need to define by yourself.

You call other stages in this lifecycle **ONLY** if you need to do something specific at those stages.

Let's take a LoginActivity as an example.

**You create the Activity like this(I know... nothing new here):**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText usr;
    public EditText pass;
    final Context context = this;
    private TextView loginButton;
    private Boolean justCreated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        initLoginButton();

        initEditTexts();

        addSwipeGesture();

        justCreated = true;
    }
```

Now let's assume that the login was validated successfully and the Activity get's to the next step in it's brief but intense lifecycle. That would be the **onPause() stage**. This means that the Activity will be in the "background".

What happens to the Strings that the user set as Username and Password?.. Well, if you do not save them somewhere then they'll get lost if the user navigates back to the Login screen(this means that the Activity is recreated).

In this case you'll need to @Override the onPause() method and do something about those Strings. For simplicity's sake I will use a created, public class called SavedValues where I'll save those Strings.

**The SavedValues class:**

```
public class SavedValues {

    private static String loginUser = "";
    private static String loginPassword = "";


    public static String getLoginUser() {
        return loginUser;
    }

    public static void setLoginUser(String loginUser) {
        SavedValues.loginUser = loginUser;
    }

    public static String getLoginPassword() {
        return loginPassword;
    }

    public static void setLoginPassword(String loginPassword) {
        SavedValues.loginPassword = loginPassword;
    }
}
```

**Now... the onPause() method included in the Activity:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText usr;
    public EditText pass;
    final Context context = this;
    private TextView loginButton;
    private Boolean justCreated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        initLoginButton();

        initEditTexts();

        addSwipeGesture();

        justCreated = true;
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SavedValues.setLoginUser(usr.getText().toString());
    SavedValues.setLoginPassword(pass.getText().toString());

    justCreated = false;
}
```

Everything fine and dandy up to this point. Now, when the user navigates back to the LoginActivity then it will enter the onResume() stage of it's lifecycle. If we do nothing about it then our saved values will not be set.

**So, we will override the onResume() method in order to retreive those values when the LoginActivity wakes up from it's slumber:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText usr;
    public EditText pass;
    final Context context = this;
    private TextView loginButton;
    private Boolean justCreated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        initLoginButton();

        initEditTexts();

        addSwipeGesture();

        justCreated = true;
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SavedValues.setLoginUser(usr.getText().toString());
    SavedValues.setLoginPassword(pass.getText().toString());

    justCreated = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (justCreated == true) //if the user recreated the activity, restore the login values from the previous instance
    {
        usr.setText(SavedValues.getLoginUser(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        pass.setText(SavedValues.getLoginPassword(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        usr.setSelection(usr.getText().length());
    }
    else //if the user only left the activity clear the login values
    {
        usr.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        pass.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

So this is how you would use some of the stages in the Activity's lifecycle to your advantage. Of course, there's more to this but I think this should get you started. Please read more on the [**Android Dev. Site**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). They have a decent documentation, albeit non-linear in a confusing sort of way.

**UPDATE**

To answer your updated question:

You can use my SavedValues example and put into it something like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Custom> yourList;

public static ArrayList<Custom> getyourList() {
        return yourList;
}

public static void setyourList(ArrayList<Custom> yourList) {
        SavedValues.yourList = yourList;
}
```

Then in your `onPause()` method you write this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    SavedValues.setyourList(getyourList()); // save the selected item list
    super.onPause();
    }
```

Now if you press the back button and return to your Activity the data should be there.

I have used an almost identical approach by using an Array adapter populated from a Oracle DB. Works like a charm.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I can see what you are doing by saving the state of the strings to reuse when the activity is reloaded. That is a great explanation of overriding the methods.

Comment: Great to hear that. Hope it clarified some parts of the lifecycle for you.

Comment: As said to codemagic i have updated my question with a new issue. Ive left it here as i believe it applys to the cycle. when i send an email in this case i press back and my listview is blank. do i need to save the list view in onPause() then load it in onresume()?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Well, it's just a classic Singleton Design Pattern... nothing fancy. Glad you find it useful.